# Оптимизации потребления оперативной памяти

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Хотелось бы уменьшить использование оперативной памяти. Какие существуют способы оптимизации использования памяти Ruby on Rails ресурса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите, в частности, сюда: [Make Your Ruby/Rails App Fast: Performance And Memory Profiling Using ruby-prof and KCachegrind](http://www.acunote.com/blog/2008/02/make-your-ruby-rails-applications-fast-performance-and-memory-profiling.html)

Answer (score 1):

Сильно зависит от используемого сервера. Если пользуетесь событийным сервером, таким как thin, unicorn, rainbows! или puma, вам достаточно одного процесса, чтобы "одновременно" обрабатывать несколько запросов. Зависит потребление памяти и от версии самого Ruby.